# Remove SCSV Cipher Suite from php curl https request

Tags: php, ssl, curl, openssl, libcurl

while making https requests using php-curl in ubuntu server, I have found that it adds an additional Cipher Suite which is identified as "EMPTY-RENEGOTIATION-INFO-SCSV".
I know this is a fake Cipher Suite, nevertheless, I want to remove this Cipher Suite from https requests.
Is there any curlopt parameter or openssl extension or apache configuration file that I can use to stop this default behavior.
Thank You

Comment: If cURL is using OpenSSL , then you need the `SSL_OP_ALLOW_UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION` option. But I'm not certain cURL uses OpenSSL when NSS is available. Also see [curl: (52) Empty reply from server](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.curl.general/12915) and OpenSSL's [`SSL_CTX_set_options` man page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_options.html).

Comment: I am also not sure whether curl is using openssl but I need the cipher to be vanished from https request. How to disable that in NSS either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "cipher" is documented in [RFC 5746 section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5746#section-3.3). This is a method that counters the prefix attack described in CVE-2009-3555 and elsewhere.

```
This SCSV is not a true cipher suite (it does not correspond to any
valid set of algorithms) and cannot be negotiated. Instead, it has
the same semantics as an empty "renegotiation_info" extension, as
described in the following sections. Because SSLv3 and TLS
implementations reliably ignore unknown cipher suites, the SCSV may
be safely sent to any server.
```

So you don't disable/enable this using the regular cipher suite option curl provides ([CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST.html)) but instead you need to ask the TLS library to allow *unsafe* renegotiations.

I don't think PHP allows you to do that and libcurl has no provided option for it, so I believe you have to patch C source code to make it happen.

This is also further described in [OpenSSL's documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_options.html#SECURE-RENEGOTIATION) for `SSL_CTX_set_options()`.

Comment: Thank You and is there any way of downgrading any version to resolve the problem?